# How to change the location of startup.log in postgresql 9.4?

Tags: postgresql, logging

my current log_directory path is

```
   /logs/demo/
```

But the startup.log file is still being created in default logs location

```
/opt/demo/PostgreSQL/9.4/data/pg_log
```

I want to change it to /logs/demo

The postgresql.conf file looks like

```
# ERROR REPORTING AND LOGGING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Where to Log -

log_destination = 'stderr'         # Valid values are combinations of
                                  # stderr, csvlog, syslog, and eventlog,
# This is used when logging to stderr:
logging_collector = on
# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
log_directory = '/logs/demo/'  #directorywherelogfiles are written
#log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'  # log file name pattern,


# These are relevant when logging to syslog:
#syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
#syslog_ident = 'postgres'

# This is only relevant when logging to eventlog (win32):
#event_source = 'PostgreSQL'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps in you case, as the log file would still be in the original location, but if you want it to be accessible in /logs/demo/, you could just symlink it:

`ln -s /opt/demo/PostgreSQL/9.4/data/pg_log /logs/demo/pg_log`